# How to update temp tables before form opens?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form `MFForm` that relies on a temp table `MFTable`.  I want to refresh the contents of this table whenever the form opens.

To do this, I'm using the following VBA code in `MFForm`:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

CurrentDb.execute "drop table MFTable", dbFailOnError
CurrentDb.execute "select * into MFTable from MFQuery", dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

But when I double-click the form to open it, I get the following error on the `drop table` command:

```
Run-time error '32111:

The database engine could not lock table 'MFTable'
because it is already in use by another person or process.
```

I think the problem is that as soon as I click on the form to run it, the temp table goes into use, even before the `Form_Open()` function executes.  How can I make sure that the table's contents are refreshed whenever the form opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I assume your table's schema is not constantly changing, and clear the table instead of dropping it.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "delete * from MFTable", dbFailOnError
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into MFTable select * from MFQuery", dbFailOnError
Me.Requery
```

If your schema is changing constantly then you will need to execute that code before the form is opened. I have not tested this but you may be able to make your form a subform of another form and have that other form drop and recreate the table before the subform opens.